# How do I display the code behind variable value on my aspx page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have a Default aspx page and and its code behind page, I want to render the value of particular variable on my code behind page to the aspx page.
For ex:-

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i=12;
}
```

Now i am using bootstrap control on my aspx page

```
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary <span class="badge">7</span></button>
```

I want to display value of i(present in c# code behind file) on the place of 7

Please guide me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easy way would be to use use a server control like a label instead of the span and you can set the text in the codebehind that way.

C#

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int i = 12;
    Lbl_Badge.Text = i.ToString();
}
```

Markup:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary <asp:Label CssClass="badge" runat="server" ID="Lbl_Badge" Text="7" /></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use an ASP Label as in @abney317's example, you can do this:

CodeBehind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    int i = 12;
    BadgeValue.InnerHtml = i.ToString();
}
```

Markup:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Primary <span class="badge" id="BadgeValue" runat="server">0</span></button>
```

Note: If you are going to be displaying text that may come from a user, you should be sure to AntiXss.HtmlEncode anything you put into a control's InnerHtml.

Comment: int i = 12;                                                                       
   BadgeValue.InnerHtml = i.ToString();                                                       Worked!!!

Comment: @abney317 Had an edit merge conflict on your change, added in the missed ToString() you suggested.